# Enable external SAS on 3ware 9750-16i4e Card

Tags: 3ware

I am adding an external  SAS enclosure to a 3ware 9750-16i4e Card. Have connected 3ware 9750-16i4e Card to 2nd 3ware 9750-16i4e Card in exteranal SAS enclosure via a Norco 1M SFF8088 to SFF8088 Cable.

Having trouble with 3ware 9750-16i4e Card is not detecting exteranal SAS enclosure.  In bios it says:"This Feature not active - No Enclosures detected"

Have looked for a option in bios to activate the feature without any luck. Is there a advanced menu / jumper that enables the feature / port on the 3ware 9750-16i4e Card?